# How to print second command line argument in shell?

Tags: unix

**how to print content of second command line argument like my shell script is**

./check.sh -f 423

so i want to print $2 i.e. 423 without doing echo $2
i have a variable called count which keeps a count  say i set it to 2
count=2

so if i do

echo "$`echo $count`"

This prints $2 and not 423.

***Please suggest me a method to do same thing.i.e. using count variable i want to print the content of $2  which is 423.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this,

```
#!/bin/bash
count=2
echo ${!count}
```